# Is it possible to join two Italian retirement funds?

Tags: retirement-funds

If I move to Italy and I work there for some years with a "contratto a progetto" (also called co.co.co or co.co.pro) I will have my retirement fund in "gestione separata", then if I find a permanent contract I will have some other retirement fund in "gestione ordinaria". Can I join the two retirement funds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways to join them:

They are called "**ricongiunzione**" (sounds like reconjunction) and "**totalizzazione**" (totalization). From these the second one is free.

This [page in Italian](http://www.forexinfo.it/Totalizzazione-contributi-come) explains how the latter works.